# Spring Data JPA @EnableJpaRepositories TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I having a spring 3.2.0.M2 setup with spring data jpa 1.2.0.RELEASE.

I also have java config. This i my Repository config class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"xxx.xxx.xxx.core.dao"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Repository {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx");
        dataSource.setUsername("xxxx");
        dataSource.setPassword("xxxx");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("xx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.domain");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }
```

When I deploy my application I get the following exception:

```
(org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader:307) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/Developer/tomcat/webapps/core/WEB-INF/classes/xx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Repository.class]; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:261)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:968)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1453)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:435)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:653)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:460)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:222)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:52)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3070)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3050)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.registerMetaAnnotations(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:247)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.doVisitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:241)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:166)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:59)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:237)
    ... 63 more
```

When I remove the @EnableJpaRepositores annotation than it works. At least I think so because than my application context will load but it will say that I have a dependency injection used. Of course caus by removing the annotation.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you try with Spring 3.1.2 ?

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem and found it was because I had both `spring-data-jpa` and `spring-data-commons-core` as dependencies in my `pom.xml`.

```
</dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Removing the `spring-data-commons-core` dependency and then ONLY having the `spring-data-jpa` dependency fixed it.

```
</dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: As of version (spring-data-jpa 1.3.0.RELEASE) spring-data-commons-core was chagned to (spring-data-commons 1.5.0.RELEASE).

Answer (score 1):

This exception is usually triggered if the JAR file containing the relevant application is missing at runtime. Are you sure you're runtime classpath contains Spring Data JPA 1.2.0.RELEASE? Make sure you're not pulling in an older version into the classpath as this might be loaded first then and cause the annotation not be found as well.

Answer (score 1):

Spring-data-commons-core is absolutely fine. Just the version we need to use must be higher. One of the classes that `@EnableJpaRepositories` extends ([RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons-core/1.4.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java#RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport)) is only in the `spring-data-commons-core 1.4.0.RELEASE`. Below works, as you need to keep both libraries:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```